# how to post the price of bitcoin from the API to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, api, express, bitcoin

I wanted to create an app where there is a function that shows the current Bitcoin price, Requested from the API of https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD. I would like to display it in an h2 element. Do you have any idea how would I do that? TIA

```js
const express = require("express");
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  const request = require("request");

  const app = express();

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

  request("https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD/", function(error, response, body) {

});

  res.send("");

  app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

```html
<h2></h2>

<form class="" action="/" method="post">
      <select class="" name="crypto">
        <option value="BTC">Bitcoin</option>
        <option value="ETH">Etherium</option>
        <option value="LTC">Litecoins</option>
      </select>
      <select class="" name="fiat">
        <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
        <option value="GPB">GB Pound</option>
        <option value="EUR">EU Euros</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" name="button">check</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Appreciated it.

Comment: Would it work for you if you made the API call directly from the front end?

Comment: I guess it would, but I can't find the exact way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

It works fine now, Thank you.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  var crypto = req.body.crypto;
  var fiat = req.body.fiat;
  var baseURL = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/";
  var finalURL =  baseURL + crypto + fiat;


  request(finalURL, function(error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var price = data.last;


    res.send("<h2>The price of " + crypto + " is " + price + " " +fiat + " </h2>");

  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

I'm able to make up a solution by observing your answers. Credit goes to you guys. Thumbs up!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need express for this, you can achieve it with a simple html page.
This code works for you:

```
<h2 id="price"></h2>
<select id="crypto">
  <option value="BTC">Bitcoin</option>
  <option value="ETH">Ethereum</option>
  <option value="LTC">Litecoin</option>
</select>
<select id="fiat">
  <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
  <option value="GBP">GB Pound</option>
  <option value="EUR">EU Euro</option>
</select>
<script>
  function updatePrice() {
    const url = 'https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/'
              + document.getElementById('crypto').value
              + document.getElementById('fiat').value;
    fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        document.getElementById('price').textContent = json.last;
      })
  }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById('crypto').onchange = () => updatePrice();
    document.getElementById('fiat').onchange = () => updatePrice();
  });
</script>
```

Plese note that I changed the value of GPB to GBP and other minor fixes on the selects.

Comment: Appreciated your answer, But as much as possible I would do it with express. Thanks @bordalix, I might use it for future reference.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a simple example using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
const url = 'https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/'

function getOption(e) {
  return e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
}

function get(n) {
  return document.getElementById(n);
}

const cryptoEl = get('crypto');
const fiatEl = get('fiat');
const buttonEl = get('button');
const priceEl = get('price');


buttonEl.onclick = async(e) => {
  const crypto = getOption(cryptoEl);
  const fiat = getOption(fiatEl);
  console.log(crypto + fiat);

  const res = await fetch(url + crypto + fiat);
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
  priceEl.innerHTML = data.ask;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="price"></h2>

<select id="crypto" class="" name="crypto">
  <option value="BTC">Bitcoin</option>
  <option value="ETH">Etherium</option>
  <option value="LTC">Litecoins</option>
</select>
<select id="fiat" class="" name="fiat">
  <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
  <option value="GPB">GB Pound</option>
  <option value="EUR">EU Euros</option>
</select>
<button id="button">check</button>
```

Comment: I try to work it out with my code, understanding it and might revise it first before I used it. I think this is closer to what I wanted, Thank you @Trobol.